# Remove tamper proof screw

Tags: screws

I would like to open up this power extension but these strange screws are in the way. I need some way to unscrew this without damaging it. Anyone know what kind of screw this is? What keyword would you search for?

[image: screw]

Comment: Go to a decent shop and purchase the bit for it.

Comment: Could also be a rivet

Comment: Maybe mention why you want to open it.  CE mark is not recognized in US/Canada as a legal electrical mark, so if there is a problem with the unit, replacement might a better idea.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. I need to send the cable through a small hole in the wall. So I thought I could disassemble it, feed the cable through and put it back together.

Answer (score 3):

Googled "Screw with three slits" and found the name "Tri-Groove Socket", that looks almost like the screws in you picture.

Answer (score 1):

They are classed ss security screws and they come in many shapes. The idea is to keep the consumer out of the boxes/ appliances.

However, any hardware store should have a selection of these bits for a screwdriver.  You can find them on sites such as ebay and aliexpress.

Comment: And Amazon (as kits of assorted "security" bits), and...